# is there any way to detect the touching of two dom elements at the same time using js touch events?

Tags: javascript, angular6

I am creating a simple app for mobile using angular6. There are two buttons in my app and I need to call a function when click/tap the two buttons at the same time. After a lot of search,  I found touch event handling functions in js.Here is my code

**app.component.ts**

```
  testfunc(event) {
    this.testval = 1;
  }

  testfunc1() {
    this.testval = 2;
  }

  testfunc2(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.testval == 1) {
      alert(this.testval);
    }
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <div class="clutchBtn" #clBtn (touchstart)="testfunc($event)"  (touchend)="testfunc1()"></div>
 <div class="gearBtn" #gearBtn (touchstart)="testfunc2($event)"></div>
```

in the above code I used 'touchstart' and 'touchend' event handlers to detect the entering and leaving of touch events in the dom elements.If the  user touches the first button then testfunc() will be called  and the value of 'testVal' will be set to 1. If the user finger removed from the first button then value of 'testVal' is set to 2.Then I add a testfun2() in the second button to detect whether the user is still touches the first button.The issue is the touch event doesn't work properly ie, when I press two buttons at the same time then the alert box will be displayed after that it still be displayed when i press only the second button. Because the value  of testVal is still '1'.how can I solve this issue?is there any other good way to detect the clicking of two buttons at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to query the element

```
@ViewChild('buttonVar') button;
touchStart1$:Observable<any>;
```

Then apply register the touch event

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.touchStart1$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'touchstart');
}
```

do that for both the button and use RxJS `forkJoin` operator to combine the two observables to wait for both actions to be clicked.

**Edit**:
In fact, do not use <strike>`forkJoin`</strike>. There are more to it to achieve that is described.
For working example, check out this stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5cjt1b

Comment: can you please post the code to combine the two observables using forkjoin ?

Comment: this.touch1 = fromEvent(this.clBtnElement.nativeElement, 'touchstart');
    this.touch2 = fromEvent(this.gearBtnElement.nativeElement, 'touchstart');
    this.joinTest = forkJoin(this.touch1, this.touch2);
    this.joinTest.subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });

Comment: but it doesn't display anything in the console when I pressed the buttons.

Comment: maybe you want to setup a stackblitz to replicate you issue and work from there?

Comment: please check the following url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b7wj6k

Comment: not working properly, when I first tap both buttons at the same time the console will be displayed and after that, it still is displayed when I pressing any of the buttons...

Comment: Btn end console log is just a log for each bottom on touchend. What you really interested in is the [event, event] log. That's when both are pressed.

Comment: I am talking about the console in the merging of the two touchend  events. The console is still be shown when clicking on any of the button after clicking two buttons at the same time.

Comment: I'm just giving an idea for your to implement your details. Not sure what are the details you are trying to achieve. Feel free to fork and try those out yourself.